Angular 18 optimization error when running ng serve configuration
I am doing a Mock App in Angular 18. Following and example I want to simulate production environment.
I just run ng generate environments without any problems and environment.ts files has been generated.
When I want to simulate Production environment and execute the command
ng serve --configuration=production

I got the error
Prebundling has been configured but will not be used because scripts optimization is enabled.

Angular.json is this
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "newstandalone": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/newstandalone",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2MB",
                  "maximumError": "5MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "qa": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "newstandalone:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "newstandalone:build:development"
            },
            "qa": {
              "buildTarget": "newstandalone:build:qa"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/azure-blue.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks.

Is this a freshly generated Angular 18 project or an existing project which has been updated to Angular 18? I cannot reproduce this in a fresh Angular 18 app. After running npx @angular/cli@18 new, navigating to the project, running ng generate environments and finally ng serve, I am not getting any warnings or errors. Please edit the question and add your angular.json.

Thanks @Derubo I added angular.json file...

I got confused with the command that gives me an error
